# R to arrange bar plots evenly

Tags: r

I am currently making a barplot that has two bars for each variables. So for two data frames (I hope I am using the right word)
`SPECIAL` and `SMALLSPECIAL`:

SPECIAL:

```
                     SPY             DIA             QQQ            
2020-11-04      "-1.108324e-02" "-1.893192e-02" "-5.951885e-02"
2020-11-08      "-6.785643e-03" "-1.662825e-02" "-5.101993e-02"
2020-11-11...5  " 3.624339e-03" "-3.637016e-02" " 9.958662e-03"
2020-11-11...6  " 4.755662e-02" " 5.783848e-04" "-1.200718e-02"
2020-11-17      " 2.105853e-02" "-6.813486e-03" "-4.538258e-02"
2020-11-19      " 5.746664e-02" " 2.564170e-02" "-3.019258e-02"
2020-11-24      " 3.270271e-02" " 9.044440e-03" "-3.057175e-02"
2020-11-29      " 3.468717e-02" " 9.997631e-03" "-4.577007e-02"
2020-12-07      " 2.643240e-02" "-7.966530e-04" "-2.941767e-02"
2020-12-08...12 " 2.854595e-02" " 4.147927e-03" "-3.488263e-02"
2020-12-08...13 " 2.198158e-02" " 7.468781e-03" "-3.320286e-02"
2020-12-10      " 3.123053e-02" " 1.188868e-02" "-1.080651e-02"
2020-12-13      " 3.277893e-02" " 1.172055e-02" "-1.257614e-02"
2020-12-15      " 3.742368e-02" " 1.791062e-02" "-1.968856e-02"
2020-12-16      "-9.995769e-03" " 6.095053e-03" "-5.634660e-02"
2020-12-27      " 1.946768e-02" "-5.515152e-02" "-2.435948e-02"
2021-01-07      " 2.429894e-03" "-8.089123e-02" "-4.014830e-02"
2021-01-13      " 2.290704e-02" "-5.468152e-02" "-3.569224e-02"
2021-01-16      " 3.215964e-02" "-9.059003e-03" "-2.208803e-02"
2021-01-19      " 3.466223e-02" "-9.474130e-03" "-2.208803e-02"
2021-01-22      " 6.763131e-03" "-1.940973e-02" "-6.704488e-02"
2021-01-23      " 1.607917e-02" "-5.184313e-03" "-3.573743e-02"
2021-01-25      " 1.607917e-02" "-5.184313e-03" "-3.573743e-02"
2021-01-29      " 2.659515e-02" " 5.448712e-03" "-2.394228e-02"
2021-02-01      " 4.756702e-02" " 2.644237e-02" "-2.966468e-03"
                IJH             IJR             IWB            
2020-11-04      "-3.103377e-02" "-3.619609e-02" "-2.983113e-02"
2020-11-08      "-3.179476e-02" "-3.035895e-02" "-3.271718e-02"
2020-11-11...5  "-4.806376e-02" "-8.113767e-02" "-2.305115e-02"
2020-11-11...6  "-2.027389e-02" "-3.397459e-02" "-1.365053e-02"
2020-11-17      "-2.566809e-02" "-2.725848e-02" "-2.436544e-02"
2020-11-19      " 8.405554e-03" " 2.334273e-02" " 1.009765e-03"
2020-11-24      "-1.946141e-02" "-9.712543e-03" "-9.149636e-03"
2020-11-29      " 1.937474e-03" " 3.035030e-02" "-1.339029e-02"
2020-12-07      "-2.553112e-02" "-3.801536e-03" "-1.903869e-02"
2020-12-08...12 "-2.186671e-02" "-1.338746e-03" "-1.875660e-02"
2020-12-08...13 "-2.168233e-02" "-9.173553e-04" "-2.485745e-02"
2020-12-10      "-1.756955e-02" "-1.474258e-03" "-1.478017e-02"
2020-12-13      "-1.849136e-02" " 1.988579e-03" "-1.535076e-02"
2020-12-15      "-1.320044e-02" " 7.058231e-03" "-7.591578e-03"
2020-12-16      "-1.469955e-02" " 1.510310e-02" "-2.371206e-02"
2020-12-27      "-2.797054e-03" " 3.867795e-02" "-1.691881e-02"
2021-01-07      "-5.096942e-02" "-1.892129e-02" "-4.095327e-02"
2021-01-13      "-1.398884e-02" " 2.946226e-02" "-2.162171e-02"
2021-01-16      "-3.863135e-03" " 3.871859e-02" "-1.108452e-02"
2021-01-19      " 5.433765e-03" " 7.280510e-02" "-1.469829e-02"
2021-01-22      "-7.608743e-03" " 6.483703e-02" "-3.329507e-02"
2021-01-23      "-2.182758e-03" " 5.912997e-02" "-1.907410e-02"
2021-01-25      "-2.182758e-03" " 5.912997e-02" "-1.907410e-02"
2021-01-29      " 2.376784e-02" " 7.057719e-02" "-6.527019e-03"
2021-02-01      " 4.400179e-02" " 8.670662e-02" " 1.209735e-02" etcetc...
```

SMALLSPECIAL:

```
 SPY             DIA             QQQ            
2021-01-19 " 3.466223e-02" "-9.474130e-03" "-2.208803e-02"
2021-01-22 " 6.763131e-03" "-1.940973e-02" "-6.704488e-02"
2021-01-23 " 1.607917e-02" "-5.184313e-03" "-3.573743e-02"
2021-01-25 " 1.607917e-02" "-5.184313e-03" "-3.573743e-02"
2021-01-29 " 2.659515e-02" " 5.448712e-03" "-2.394228e-02"
2021-02-01 " 4.756702e-02" " 2.644237e-02" "-2.966468e-03"
           IJH             IJR             IWB            
2021-01-19 " 5.433765e-03" " 7.280510e-02" "-1.469829e-02"
2021-01-22 "-7.608743e-03" " 6.483703e-02" "-3.329507e-02"
2021-01-23 "-2.182758e-03" " 5.912997e-02" "-1.907410e-02"
2021-01-25 "-2.182758e-03" " 5.912997e-02" "-1.907410e-02"
2021-01-29 " 2.376784e-02" " 7.057719e-02" "-6.527019e-03"
2021-02-01 " 4.400179e-02" " 8.670662e-02" " 1.209735e-02"
```

So apparently `SMALLSPECIAL` is a smaller version of `SPECIAL` in terms of fewer dates, but same datas.

I have used barplot codes to make two barplots to each other using `beside = T`. So,

```
barplot(SMALLSPECIAL,ylim=c(-2.0,2.0),col = rainbow(1),width = 0.1,space = c(2,2,2),main = ,border=NA)
barplot(SPECIAL,ylim=c(-2.0,2.0), col = "blue",width = 0.1,border=NA,add=T)
```

But there was an error saying:

> Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator

So instead I used `add = T`.

So the code would be

```
barplot(SMALLSPECIAL,ylim=c(-2.0,2.0),col = rainbow(1),width = 0.1,space = 2,border=NA)
barplot(SPECIAL,ylim=c(-2.0,2.0), col = "blue",width = 0.1, space = 3,border=NA,add=T)
```

The barplots revealed but the bars were overlapped in a strange way.

[image: barplots]

I finally figured out how to arrange these graphs but the code was too long and messy. Take a look:

```
barplot(SMALLSPECIAL,ylim=c(-2.0,2.0),col = rainbow(1),width = 0.1,space = 2,border=NA)
barplot(SPECIAL,ylim=c(-2.0,2.0), col = "blue",width = 0.1, space = c(3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),border=NA,add=T)
```

[image: new barplots]

It was to add 2 for every points in the `space = c()`.

However, not only for these dataframes, I have a lot more in the folder and I cannot always count the variables I have to put the numbers in. Moreover, I believe the `space` and `width` will differ from each and every data frames. (I have SPECIAL2,3,4,........)

Is there any way to arrange my `SPECIAL` and `SMALLSPECIAL` barplots evenly beside each other?

Thanks.

```
 dput(SPECIAL)
structure(c("-1.108324e-02", "-6.785643e-03", " 3.624339e-03", 
" 4.755662e-02", " 2.105853e-02", " 5.746664e-02", " 3.270271e-02", 
" 3.468717e-02", " 2.643240e-02", " 2.854595e-02", " 2.198158e-02", 
" 3.123053e-02", " 3.277893e-02", " 3.742368e-02", "-9.995769e-03", 
" 1.946768e-02", " 2.429894e-03", " 2.290704e-02", " 3.215964e-02", 
" 3.466223e-02", " 6.763131e-03", " 1.607917e-02", " 1.607917e-02", 
" 2.659515e-02", " 4.756702e-02", "-1.893192e-02", "-1.662825e-02", 
"-3.637016e-02", " 5.783848e-04", "-6.813486e-03", " 2.564170e-02", 
" 9.044440e-03", " 9.997631e-03", "-7.966530e-04", " 4.147927e-03", 
" 7.468781e-03", " 1.188868e-02", " 1.172055e-02", " 1.791062e-02", 
" 6.095053e-03", "-5.515152e-02", "-8.089123e-02", "-5.468152e-02", 
"-9.059003e-03", "-9.474130e-03", "-1.940973e-02", "-5.184313e-03", 
"-5.184313e-03", " 5.448712e-03", " 2.644237e-02", "-5.951885e-02", 
"-5.101993e-02", " 9.958662e-03", "-1.200718e-02", "-4.538258e-02", 
"-3.019258e-02", "-3.057175e-02", "-4.577007e-02", "-2.941767e-02", 
"-3.488263e-02", "-3.320286e-02", "-1.080651e-02", "-1.257614e-02", 
"-1.968856e-02", "-5.634660e-02", "-2.435948e-02", "-4.014830e-02", 
"-3.569224e-02", "-2.208803e-02", "-2.208803e-02", "-6.704488e-02", 
"-3.573743e-02", "-3.573743e-02", "-2.394228e-02", "-2.966468e-03", 
"-3.103377e-02", "-3.179476e-02", "-4.806376e-02", "-2.027389e-02", 
"-2.566809e-02", " 8.405554e-03", "-1.946141e-02", " 1.937474e-03", 
"-2.553112e-02", "-2.186671e-02", "-2.168233e-02", "-1.756955e-02", 
"-1.849136e-02", "-1.320044e-02", "-1.469955e-02", "-2.797054e-03", 
"-5.096942e-02", "-1.398884e-02", "-3.863135e-03", " 5.433765e-03", 
"-7.608743e-03", "-2.182758e-03", "-2.182758e-03", " 2.376784e-02", 
" 4.400179e-02", "-3.619609e-02", "-3.035895e-02", "-8.113767e-02", 
"-3.397459e-02", "-2.725848e-02", " 2.334273e-02", "-9.712543e-03", 
" 3.035030e-02", "-3.801536e-03", "-1.338746e-03", "-9.173553e-04", 
"-1.474258e-03", " 1.988579e-03", " 7.058231e-03", " 1.510310e-02", 
" 3.867795e-02", "-1.892129e-02", " 2.946226e-02", " 3.871859e-02", 
" 7.280510e-02", " 6.483703e-02", " 5.912997e-02", " 5.912997e-02", 
" 7.057719e-02", " 8.670662e-02", "-2.983113e-02", "-3.271718e-02", 
"-2.305115e-02", "-1.365053e-02", "-2.436544e-02", " 1.009765e-03", 
"-9.149636e-03", "-1.339029e-02", "-1.903869e-02", "-1.875660e-02", 
"-2.485745e-02", "-1.478017e-02", "-1.535076e-02", "-7.591578e-03", 
"-2.371206e-02", "-1.691881e-02", "-4.095327e-02", "-2.162171e-02", 
"-1.108452e-02", "-1.469829e-02", "-3.329507e-02", "-1.907410e-02", 
"-1.907410e-02", "-6.527019e-03", " 1.209735e-02", "-2.800942e-02", 
"-5.267162e-03", "-4.886728e-02", "-7.771789e-03", "-1.676049e-04", 
" 3.047727e-02", " 1.057285e-03", " 3.114247e-02", " 2.155299e-02", 
" 2.057688e-02", " 1.876534e-02", " 2.624163e-02", " 2.144208e-02", 
" 2.343194e-02", " 2.892165e-02", " 1.040049e-01", " 6.054478e-02", 
" 1.396324e-01", " 1.410700e-01", " 1.668152e-01", " 1.320362e-01", 
" 1.271185e-01", " 1.271185e-01", " 1.497892e-01", " 1.674645e-01", 
"-2.952869e-02", "-3.544803e-02", "-2.104514e-02", "-1.001015e-02", 
"-2.291980e-02", " 1.403102e-04", "-1.205648e-02", "-1.516355e-02", 
"-2.575451e-02", "-2.491258e-02", "-2.729815e-02", "-1.808772e-02", 
"-1.795295e-02", "-1.075697e-02", "-3.018192e-02", "-2.574466e-02", 
"-5.010076e-02", "-2.898847e-02", "-1.584816e-02", "-1.710806e-02", 
"-3.619450e-02", "-2.187872e-02", "-2.187872e-02", "-6.023641e-03", 
" 1.309558e-02", "-3.390737e-02", "-3.832097e-02", " 1.242357e-03", 
"-2.307181e-03", "-2.420787e-02", "-5.597597e-03", "-1.261939e-02", 
"-2.673585e-02", "-2.576659e-02", "-2.638960e-02", "-3.027626e-02", 
"-1.694511e-02", "-1.710408e-02", "-1.471415e-02", "-3.915599e-02", 
"-3.087067e-02", "-4.603758e-02", "-3.184428e-02", "-2.735673e-02", 
"-3.706707e-02", "-7.023122e-02", "-4.832820e-02", "-4.832820e-02", 
"-3.059222e-02", "-1.090184e-02", "-3.171609e-02", "-3.679614e-02", 
"-2.628667e-02", "-1.845287e-02", "-2.684457e-02", " 9.221679e-04", 
"-2.265155e-02", "-1.402867e-02", "-3.420606e-02", "-3.226893e-02", 
"-3.154920e-02", "-2.571265e-02", "-2.780519e-02", "-2.710868e-02", 
"-3.180983e-02", "-2.309161e-02", "-9.755660e-02", "-6.842524e-02", 
"-5.168392e-02", "-4.509838e-02", "-6.897000e-02", "-6.411096e-02", 
"-6.411096e-02", "-3.028198e-02", "-1.170450e-02", "-3.665475e-02", 
"-3.432511e-02", "-6.982301e-02", "-3.904844e-02", "-4.164457e-02", 
"-1.778814e-03", "-3.019193e-02", "-1.265701e-02", "-3.939310e-02", 
"-3.992061e-02", "-4.131222e-02", "-3.895565e-02", "-4.061518e-02", 
"-4.417682e-02", "-3.025861e-02", "-9.467246e-03", "-3.128756e-02", 
" 2.743353e-02", " 3.406697e-02", " 5.683112e-02", " 4.306356e-02", 
" 4.093694e-02", " 4.093694e-02", " 5.532050e-02", " 7.080921e-02", 
"-1.883909e-02", "-1.009265e-02", "-4.891129e-02", "-9.531920e-03", 
"-1.671212e-03", " 3.252497e-02", " 1.283937e-02", " 3.690898e-02", 
" 1.970907e-02", " 2.563016e-02", " 2.249331e-02", " 2.353251e-02", 
" 2.948842e-02", " 4.710904e-02", " 4.459910e-02", " 4.370260e-02", 
" 1.098265e-02", " 3.722300e-02", " 5.119763e-02", " 5.446150e-02", 
" 4.740523e-02", " 6.084719e-02", " 6.084719e-02", " 7.085115e-02", 
" 9.040153e-02", "-4.164067e-02", "-3.654214e-02", "-8.631011e-02", 
"-3.567167e-02", "-4.008430e-02", " 1.361761e-03", "-2.146112e-02", 
" 1.342928e-02", "-2.468903e-02", "-1.868924e-02", "-1.905253e-02", 
"-1.870615e-02", "-1.592629e-02", "-5.241319e-03", "-1.063192e-02", 
"-9.999412e-04", "-5.375490e-03", " 4.966019e-02", " 6.709888e-02", 
" 8.285351e-02", " 7.418137e-02", " 8.072642e-02", " 8.072642e-02", 
" 9.624642e-02", " 1.191058e-01", "-4.266885e-02", "-3.278322e-02", 
"-1.032246e-01", "-4.280275e-02", "-4.296781e-02", " 1.556543e-03", 
"-3.269052e-02", " 1.176407e-02", "-3.181170e-02", "-2.474552e-02", 
"-2.575198e-02", "-2.696554e-02", "-1.939234e-02", "-1.019759e-02", 
"-4.207860e-03", " 1.026277e-02", "-1.943329e-02", " 3.724595e-02", 
" 5.157572e-02", " 7.657735e-02", " 6.864593e-02", " 5.768984e-02", 
" 5.768984e-02", " 6.706270e-02", " 8.003198e-02", "-1.613727e-02", 
"-1.075309e-02", "-7.945726e-02", "-1.895981e-02", "-1.896545e-02", 
" 2.253905e-02", "-7.182803e-03", " 2.944441e-02", "-4.085063e-03", 
" 2.596171e-03", " 3.758152e-03", " 2.623379e-03", " 9.993320e-03", 
" 3.233074e-02", " 3.078537e-02", " 2.162652e-02", "-2.385175e-02", 
" 6.258800e-03", " 9.119781e-03", " 1.991368e-02", " 1.682176e-02", 
" 1.946446e-02", " 1.946446e-02", " 2.551132e-02", " 4.703518e-02", 
"-2.318131e-02", "-1.289303e-02", "-4.455112e-02", " 2.426609e-03", 
"-1.274251e-02", " 6.156825e-03", "-1.260365e-02", " 1.752782e-02", 
" 9.244847e-03", " 1.427311e-02", " 1.869845e-02", " 2.200304e-02", 
" 2.744960e-02", " 3.485790e-02", " 6.029203e-02", " 1.114360e-01", 
" 1.071467e-01", " 1.361288e-01", " 1.511512e-01", " 1.511512e-01", 
" 1.545835e-01", " 1.686660e-01", " 1.686660e-01", " 1.884617e-01", 
" 2.099762e-01"), .Dim = c(25L, 16L), .Dimnames = list(c("2020-11-04", 
"2020-11-08", "2020-11-11...5", "2020-11-11...6", "2020-11-17", 
"2020-11-19", "2020-11-24", "2020-11-29", "2020-12-07", "2020-12-08...12", 
"2020-12-08...13", "2020-12-10", "2020-12-13", "2020-12-15", 
"2020-12-16", "2020-12-27", "2021-01-07", "2021-01-13", "2021-01-16", 
"2021-01-19", "2021-01-22", "2021-01-23", "2021-01-25", "2021-01-29", 
"2021-02-01"), c("SPY", "DIA", "QQQ", "IJH", "IJR", "IWB", "IWM", 
"IWV", "IVW", "IJK", "IJT", "IVE", "IJJ", "IJS", "DVY", "RSP"
)))
```

```
dput(SMALLSPECIAL)
structure(c(" 3.466223e-02", " 6.763131e-03", " 1.607917e-02", 
" 1.607917e-02", " 2.659515e-02", " 4.756702e-02", "-9.474130e-03", 
"-1.940973e-02", "-5.184313e-03", "-5.184313e-03", " 5.448712e-03", 
" 2.644237e-02", "-2.208803e-02", "-6.704488e-02", "-3.573743e-02", 
"-3.573743e-02", "-2.394228e-02", "-2.966468e-03", " 5.433765e-03", 
"-7.608743e-03", "-2.182758e-03", "-2.182758e-03", " 2.376784e-02", 
" 4.400179e-02", " 7.280510e-02", " 6.483703e-02", " 5.912997e-02", 
" 5.912997e-02", " 7.057719e-02", " 8.670662e-02", "-1.469829e-02", 
"-3.329507e-02", "-1.907410e-02", "-1.907410e-02", "-6.527019e-03", 
" 1.209735e-02", " 1.668152e-01", " 1.320362e-01", " 1.271185e-01", 
" 1.271185e-01", " 1.497892e-01", " 1.674645e-01", "-1.710806e-02", 
"-3.619450e-02", "-2.187872e-02", "-2.187872e-02", "-6.023641e-03", 
" 1.309558e-02", "-3.706707e-02", "-7.023122e-02", "-4.832820e-02", 
"-4.832820e-02", "-3.059222e-02", "-1.090184e-02", "-4.509838e-02", 
"-6.897000e-02", "-6.411096e-02", "-6.411096e-02", "-3.028198e-02", 
"-1.170450e-02", " 5.683112e-02", " 4.306356e-02", " 4.093694e-02", 
" 4.093694e-02", " 5.532050e-02", " 7.080921e-02", " 5.446150e-02", 
" 4.740523e-02", " 6.084719e-02", " 6.084719e-02", " 7.085115e-02", 
" 9.040153e-02", " 8.285351e-02", " 7.418137e-02", " 8.072642e-02", 
" 8.072642e-02", " 9.624642e-02", " 1.191058e-01", " 7.657735e-02", 
" 6.864593e-02", " 5.768984e-02", " 5.768984e-02", " 6.706270e-02", 
" 8.003198e-02", " 1.991368e-02", " 1.682176e-02", " 1.946446e-02", 
" 1.946446e-02", " 2.551132e-02", " 4.703518e-02", " 1.511512e-01", 
" 1.545835e-01", " 1.686660e-01", " 1.686660e-01", " 1.884617e-01", 
" 2.099762e-01"), .Dim = c(6L, 16L), .Dimnames = list(c("2021-01-19", 
"2021-01-22", "2021-01-23", "2021-01-25", "2021-01-29", "2021-02-01"
), c("SPY", "DIA", "QQQ", "IJH", "IJR", "IWB", "IWM", "IWV", 
"IVW", "IJK", "IJT", "IVE", "IJJ", "IJS", "DVY", "RSP")))
```

Comment: Please supply some data. It makes it easier to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Oh I almost forgot. The x-axis names are overlapped also weirdly so I have used `xlab = NA` but nothing happened :( How to erase the x-axis labels for only to appear once? Thanks.

Comment: Umm...... I think I supplied the data SPECIAL and SMALLSPECIAL? Is there anything more necessary? Thanks.

Comment: You need to supply it in readable format by using `dput(SPECIAL)`. It's very cumbersome to type up your data manually ...

Comment: I've added dput structure! Thanks for the advice!